# Link RtAudio into another project using CMakeLists

Tags: c++, cmake, rtaudio

I'm trying to use RtAudio to generate streaming audio. However, when I try to include "RtAudio.h" file, the program always complain something weird. My project structure looks like:

- Project

  - rtaudio

    - CMakeList1
    - RtAudio.h
  - demos

    - main.cpp
    - CMakeList2
  - CMakeList

Basically, the folder rtaudio is the repository I installed from [here](https://github.com/thestk/rtaudio) and the CMakeList1 is also from there.

CMakeList under the main folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
# Add -Wall and -Wextra. Also,
# treat C/C++ warnings as errors if -DADM_FATAL_WARNINGS=ON.
include (cmake/FatalWarnings.cmake)
ADM_EXTRA_WARNINGS()
add_subdirectory(demos)
```

CMakeList2:

```
project(malos_service C CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_definitions(-std=c++11)
FIND_LIBRARY(WIRINGPI_LIB NAMES wiringPi) 
....

set(AUDIO_LIBRARY_FOUND OFF)
find_path(RTAUDIO_HEADER_PATH "RtAudio.h" HINTS ../rtaudio)
if(RTAUDIO_HEADER_PATH)
    message(STATUS "Compiling provided rtaudio-library!")
    add_subdirectory(../rtaudio rtaudio)
    add_definitions(-DRTAUDIO_HEADER="../rtaudio/RtAudio.h")
    set(AUDIO_LIBRARY_FOUND ON)
endif()
if (NOT AUDIO_LIBRARY_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "no supported library")
endif()

# Check if any audio-library was added
if(NOT AUDIO_LIBRARY_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "No supported audio-library found!")
endif()
....


add_executable(...)
```

To compile these, under Project folder,

```
mkdir build 
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

In main, I just add:

```
#include "../rtaudio/RtAudio.h"
```

After I compile ***make***, I will get a lot of error:

```
In file included from ~/Project/demos/main.cpp:7:0:
/home/pi/Downloads/Project/demos/../rtaudio/RtAudio.h:729:5: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
     OUTPUT,
     ^
/home/pi/Downloads/Project/demos/../rtaudio/RtAudio.h:729:5: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
/home/pi/Downloads/Project/demos/../rtaudio/RtAudio.h:729:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
In file included from /home/pi/Downloads/Project/demos/main.cpp:25:0:
/home/pi/Downloads/Project/demos/../rtaudio/RtAudio.h: In member function ‘bool RtApi::isStreamOpen() const’:
/home/pi/Downloads/Project/demos/../rtaudio/RtAudio.h:709:44: error: ‘stream_’ was not declared in this scope
   bool isStreamOpen( void ) const { return stream_.state != STREAM_CLOSED; }
...
```

***PS: if I directly cmake rtaudio, the program under rtaudio is all working, which means the error should not comes from rtaudio *** (Hopefully)

Is the way I cmake has problem? Is anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Smells like you have `OUTPUT` macro or enumeration constant **already defined**. It is difficult to say more without viewing **your code** (before including the `RtAudio.h`) too. You may also try to move `#include` directive to the top of your code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev My code is working without including the RtAudio.h. But I need to include that project to use their structure. And I double checked there is no overlapped definition for OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting all of those errors is because you aren't compiling the source code from `RtAudio` with your project. you need to copy the `RtAudio.cpp` file into your project. It appears you are using a raspberry pi, so really all you need to do to compile your project is to set up your files like this:

```
- Project
  - RtAudio.h
  - RtAudio.cpp
  - main.cpp
```

then to compile, you will want to run

```
g++ main.cpp RtAudio.cpp -o run
```

that's it! assuming that you have the dependencies of RtAudio installed, it should compile without issue.

Comment: I tried similar stuff and the error message is still the same. And according to the hint provided by @Tsyvarev, I notice if I change the name "OUTPUT" into another name then the code compiles. However, I still cannot find the structure inside rtaudio. There must be something wrong to the way I link the library.